# Can install an app due to wrong php version

Tags: php

I have just found the required code snippet.

```html
<?php


class 
    RedSparkInstaller_RsModule_Installer_Model_Dataobject_Requirement_PHPVersion
extends
    RedSparkInstaller_RsModule_Installer_Model_Dataobject_Requirement
{

    /**
     * Constructor inits the requirement.
     * 
     * Check the requirements automatically.
     */
    public function __construct($options = Array()) {
        parent::__construct($options);

        // PHP version is strictly required
        $this->_optional = false;

        // Check php Version
        $ver = explode('.',PHP_VERSION);

        // Note on old, unsupported versions.
        $this->_description = sprintf('It is hardly recommended to use an up-to-date version of PHP (5.3.8 or later). Beside security reasons, there are some known, unfixed bugs in older versions.');

        // Not 5.2 or 5.3
        if ($ver[0] != 5 || $ver[1] < 2 || $ver[1] > 3) {
            $this->_found = false;
            $this->_notfoundtext = 'You need to install PHP in Version >= 5.2.x or 5.3.x. Your Version is '.PHP_VERSION;
        // An old version of 5.3
        } else if ($ver[1]==3 && $ver[2] <= 4) {
            $this->_notfoundtext = sprintf('PHP %s', PHP_VERSION);
            $this->_optional = true;
            $this->_found = false;
        } else {
            $this->_notfoundtext = sprintf('PHP %s', PHP_VERSION);
            $this->_found = true;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]I am getting error msg from `<?php echo$req->getStatusText() ?>`

the complete code is shown below

```html
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col width="*">
        <col width="50">
        <col width="150">
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>   
<?php foreach($this->requirements AS $req): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" class="open arrow"><?php echo $req->getName(); ?></a></td>
        <td class="center">
            <?php 
                switch($req->getStatus()) {
                    case 0: echo '<img src="/templates/installer/img/icons/cross.png" title="Missing">'; break;
                    case 1: echo '<img src="/templates/installer/img/icons/tick.png" title="OK">'; break;
                    case 2: echo '<img src="/templates/installer/img/icons/bullet_orange.png" title="Missing, but optional">'; break;
                }
             ?>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo$req->getStatusText() ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden">
        <td class="description"><?php echo $req->getDescription(); ?></td>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

when I am trying to install a php app it is giving me error message

```
You need to install PHP in Version >= 5.2.x or 5.3.x. Your Version is 5.5.11
```

in the Bootstrap.php file I have found the php version checking logic.

```
/**
 * Check that PHP is installed at least in Version 5.2.x
 * Throw exception if not 
 */
protected function checkRequirements() {
    /* skip check in live systems */
    if (config_site_is_live) {
        return;
    }

    /* Check php Version */
    $ver = explode('.',PHP_VERSION);
    if ($ver[0] < 5 || $ver[1] < 2) {
        throw new Exception('You need to install PHP in Version >= 5.2. Your Version is '.phpversion());    
    }

    /* Check PDO */
    $pdo = phpversion('PDO');
    $pdo_mysql = phpversion('pdo_mysql');
    if (!$pdo || !$pdo_mysql) {
        throw new Exception('You need to install the PDO and pdo_mysql extension');
    }

    /* Check simplexml */
    $xml = phpversion('simplexml');
    if (!$xml) {
        throw new Exception('You need to install the simplexml extension');
    }

    /* Check fileinfo */
    $finfo = function_exists('finfo_file');
    if (!$finfo) {
        #throw new Exception('You need to install the fileinfo extension');
    }

    /* Check gd */
    $gd = function_exists('ImageCreateTrueColor');
    if (!$gd) {
        throw new Exception('You need to install the gd extension');
    }

    /* Check mbstring */
    $mb = function_exists('mb_strlen');
    if (!$mb) {
        throw new Exception('You need to install the mbstring extension');
    }

    /* Safe mode must be switched off */
    $safe = ini_get('safe_mode');
    if ($safe) {
        throw new Exception('safe_mode must be switched off in your php.ini');
    }

    /* open_basedir mode must be switched off */
    $safe = ini_get('open_basedir');
    if ($safe) {
        throw new Exception('open_basedir must be switched off in your php.ini');
    }
}

/**
 * Check that PHP is installed at least in Version 5.2.x
 * Throw exception if not 
 */
```

I have tried to manipulate the code above, but I cannot install the app. Can you give me an insight how to do it?

Comment: Remove the if clause?

Comment: The Exception you get doesn't get thrown there. The messages are different.

Comment: Can you do a search for the string "You need to install PHP in Version >= 5.2.x or 5.3.x." ? As Alrazah points out, the exception is thrown else where.

Comment: Yes, I am searching it right now.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a project that isn't being maintained anymore?

Comment: I plan to extract some codes out of this project that could be valuable.

Comment: Removed the code snippets.  This functionality is only for HTML/CSS/JavaScript; you cannot run PHP within the OP.

Comment: So there are two inconsistent version checks. 5.5 will pass the second one (posted near the bottom) but fail this one `if ($ver[0] != 5 || $ver[1] < 2 || $ver[1] > 3)`  Remove the `|| $ver[1] > 3` from that block and it should load with 5.5. That does not mean it will all work correctly with 5.5 due to deprecations, etc.

Comment: Or just comment out the entire if/elseif/else block following `// Not 5.2 or 5.3` to disable the version check in its entirety.